# C calculation result incomprehensible

Tags: c, cs50

Why I can not get a result of 2 while giving input of 2.2 as a float.

With my code, 2.2 should get converted to 220, and when it goes through the first for loop I should get a remainder of 20 (which is fine as it gives me 8 coins).
But when it goes through the second loop, I can not get 20/10 = 2, I always get `1`.

By the way if I just put dime <= 20, I will get 2 hmm. I don't understand why since the remainder is equal to 20 as well.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float change ;
    float quarter ;
    float dime  ;
    float nickel ;
    float penny = 1;
    int coins = 0;
    int coins1 = 0;
    int coins2 = 0;
    int coins3 = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int remainder ;

    do
    {
        printf("What is the owed change: \n");
        change = GetFloat();
        change = round(change * 100);
        printf("%f\n", change);
    }

    while(change < 0);

    for(quarter = 25; quarter <= change; quarter+=25)
    {
        remainder = change - quarter;
        coins++;
    }

    printf("%d,%d\n", remainder,coins);

    for (dime = 10; dime <= remainder; dime += 10)  //This is where the problem starts.
    {
        remainder = remainder - dime;
        coins1++;
    }

    printf("%d,%d\n", remainder,coins1);

    for (nickel = 5; nickel < remainder; nickel += 5)
    {
        remainder = remainder - nickel;
        coins2++;
    }

    printf("%d,%d\n", remainder,coins2);

    for (penny = 1; penny < remainder; penny += 1)
    {
        remainder = remainder - penny;
        coins3++;
    }

    printf("%d,%d\n", remainder,coins3);
    printf("\n%d\n", sum = coins + coins1 + coins2 + coins3);
}
```

Comment: You believe to have 2.2 in the variable, but in fact it might be 2.199999999999999 which is a bit lower than 2.2 and thus leads to the results you see.

Comment: @WernerHenze: good observation, although `2.2` is more commonly stored as `2.2000000476837158203125` (`0x400CCCCD`) – a bit more, not less. But the problem may be related: why are all those integer calculations done on `float` types? Does it magically work if you change everything to `int`? (Except for the very first ask/convert-to-int line.)

Comment: @RadLexus Unfortunately, since the question was migrated and the user hasn't registered on SO, I doubt you will get an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're subtracting `dime` from `remainder` during each run of the `for` loop, while `dime` is being increased during each iteration of the loop. Let's suppose that change is initially 20 before the second `for` loop. The first loop execution will subtract 10, leaving `remainder`as 10. Then `dime` is incremented by 10 and is now 20. The loop condition fails because 20 > 10, and the loop runs only once.

My advice is to give your variables more intuitive names, like `i` or `x` for basic loop counters and `dimes_needed` instead of `coins1`